# Usb wifi adapter always disconnecting after a while

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface, networkmanager

Hi I am using AWUS036h wifi adapter on Kali linux 2016.2 running on a virtual box on my mac. I am able to connect to my wireless but after less than 5 minutest I can't access the internet anymore, I stay connected and with an ip address but I can't reach the internet anymore. For example if I am pinging to google or even to my router I get host unreachable after a while.

Note on virtual box I selected not attached for network. I think the problem is from the network manager of kali but I tried uninstalling the default network manager and installing wicd but I continued with the same problem.

I also tried uninstalling kali and reinstalling and I stayed with the same error.

Moreover when I ran windows 7 on my virtual box with the same vm settings that I used in kali it worked perfectly and never disconnects.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same Wi-Fi card. It's based on the RTL8187L chipset, so you're going to need the `firmware-realtek` package if you want it to work properly.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Note that it's apart of the non-free repository, so if you don't have that, you'll need to add it to your /etc/apt/sources.list and then `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I already have it installed and with the newest version